# Magento 1.9 backend having SSL issue after moving from centos 6 to Debian 8

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

On the former server, I have an SSL certificate installed, i think that's the problem, I copied the certificate to the new server.
I can access the front end with all functionalities, but the admin login page cannot log css and js files resulting in an ugly page.
however after loggedin anyway, I cannot save settings.
In google chrome I allowed the loading of unsecure scripts,I was able to figure out that the secure url was set. But viewing the source of the page, all js and css urls are non SSL, although in core_config_data, the secure version has https.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out, in my case the website allowed connection from SSL and non SSL, so I had two vhost files, one for non SSL and one for SSL, it appeared that the SSL vhost file was different from the non SSL, copying the exact content made it work.
Of course what is different is the port, and the custom log location.